# Test tool for structured data

Tags: javascript, structure, price

I'm getting errors while running the test tool for structured data. Finding no solution or explanation for what is wrong. Google presents errors in Swedish, not allowing me to google the issue nor are google giving any links to explain what is the problem. I'm trying to add structured data to a website and include both offers and rating. Once I try to run the snippet through the test tool Google says it can not normalize the value for the price. I have no idea what this means, and there is no information to be found on it either.

This is what my script looks like:

```js
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org/",
      "@type": "Product",
      "image": "https://www.test.com/bild.png",
      "name": "Produktnamn",  
      "description": "Beskrivning.",
      "brand": {
        "@type": "Product",
        "name": "Företag"
      },
      "aggregateRating": {
        "@type": "AggregateRating",
        "ratingValue": "15",
        "reviewCount": "3",
        "worstRating": "1",
        "bestRating": "5"
      },
      "offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "priceCurrency": "sek",
        "price": "519",
        "priceValidUntil": "2019-01-01",
        "itemCondition": "http://schema.org/NewCondition",
        "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
        "url": "https://www.test.com/produktsida"
      }    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used **ratingValue** as **15** which is outside the range you have defined for **worstRating** and **bestRating**.

Either your value should be corrected to fit between 1 and 5 or your range is wrong.